# Windows 10 Green and White Login Screen

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

So I just woke up to this. I can't login, rebooting didn't solve the issue. There are no loose video connections, and the cards are securely mounted in place. I'm certain this is software because **I can still move the mouse.**

What happened?

Screenshot:

[image: God help me]

**Edit:** Apparently it was installing updates, because I didn't do anything and now its just fine. Still, I'd very much like to know what was going on for the future.

Comment: That looks very much like a graphics card error. Since you fixed the issue, it was probably faulty driver.

Comment: Or a loose cable, incorrect resolution, or incorrect frequency.

Comment: If you found a solution for that issue plz write it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the request of @[Stackcraft_noob](https://superuser.com/users/538039/stackcraft-noob), I'm posting my answer.

I have no idea what I did to fix this. I rebooted my machine a couple of times and it came back. I think there was something going on with the driver, or an update that was processing? I have no clue. But rebooting the machine did eliminate the issue.